# How to convert a sql to spark dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Val test=sql ("Select * from table1) which returns a dataframe. I want to convert it to dataset which is not working.
test.toDS is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more detail about the error.

If you want to convert a dataframe in dataset use the code below :

```
case class MyClass(field1: Int, field2: Long) // for example

val df = sql ("Select * from table1)
val ds : Dataset[MyClass] = df.as[MyClass]
```